# Which logs to track regularly

Tags: ubuntu, log-files, logging

I run my own server at home for my personal website running Ubuntu Server with Apache, Bind9 and Django. What logs would you suggest are best to keep track of on a regular basis? (rather than on a basis of reading when something goes wrong). I'm thinking for the detection of intrusion attempts  (I've previously experienced SSH errors) and unusual traffic or errors on my site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Logs of interest:

- /var/log/apache2/* - apache2 logs :)
- /var/log/auth.log - authentication attempts
- /var/log/daemon.log - system processes log here
- /var/log/syslog - everything logs here

I use the [logwatch](http://www.logwatch.org/) package for monitoring SMTP traffic and SSH logins, and authentication attempts. It is available from most Linux distributions, including Ubuntu by default.

```
aptitude install logwatch
```

In the past I have also used [logsurfer+](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/) which is a complicated piece of software, but highly configurable.

If neither of these tools (logwatch, logsurfer+) meets your needs, there's a large number of log management solutions from various vendors. From software packages to dedicated devices. Here's a few to get started if you want to do additional research. I am not affiliated with any of these companies or products.

- [Splunk](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.splunk.com%2F&ei=impwSoG9EYmKMa_o4ecI&usg=AFQjCNH0mmqx1CLXBHPhtOcJYpTuByD2zw&sig2=JP1vPONxcSZ4FuJ5Xxxg4Q)
- [ArcSight](http://www.arcsight.com/solutions/solutions-logmanagement/)
- [AlertLogic](http://www.alertlogic.com/products/logmgmt.php)
- [SANS Institute has many additional resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asans.org+log+management)

Comment: +1 for logwatch; that saves me a lot of time in the mornings.

Comment: I lurves mah logwatch.

Comment: Logwatch seems great - even showed up something that I needed to check into on the first run!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using OSSEC to monitor your logs. It will auto-detect the important log files and monitor all of them in real time by default.

If you are using Ubuntu, it will look at all authentication logs, apache logs, apt-get logs (to see when new apps are installed), etc.

It is open source, has an active development team and is simple to use. We migrated to it from logwatch, because it looks at the logs in real time instead of doing that every X hours like log watch does.

Link: http://www.ossec.net

Answer (score 0):

I generally watch the above files, but mostly the syslog files (/var/log/messages).  I usually set up syslog-ng to provide some better filtering, and I set up syslog to log as *.debug so that I can see everything.  This is all read by a shell script which has its roots in logcheck.sh (sorry, lost the link) and mails me interesting items daily.  This has an increased amount of noise that is hard to filter out, but I use the noise level as a health check too -- if the noise level suddenly increases or decreases, something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have one caveat about logwatch and that is "what" to look for. I wrote/use a tool called petit  to perform word discovery and correlation. It uses a couple of simple techniques from Natural Language Processing to remove stopwords. This helps an admin/analyst who is responsible for log analysis to feel more confident that he/she is, indeed, catching all of the events that he/she wants to with logwatch.

It's a basic chicken/egg problem of how do I know what I need to search for until I've seen it before. The word discovery mode of petit helps with this. Also it provides cli graphing and hashing.

Link: http://opensource.eyemg.com/Petit